# Can a client send multiple FTP commands on the control connection before the server begins responding?

Tags: ftp

This question is due to an assumption I always had, but suddenly I'm unsure of, yet I can't find a clear answer to.

As far as I know, in an FTP control connection, the client sends a command, the server responds, the client sends another command, and so on.

However, is it possible for the client to send more than one command, and the server will respond to all the commands (either in order or not)?

For example:

```
> PWD
> PASV
257 /home/admin
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,150,90,195,149).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servers process the commands as they come, one by one. So if you queue multiple commands, a server will actually not even realize, that you have sent the other commands without waiting for a response to the previous ones.

Comment: So I take it that my original assumption was wrong then. Thanks!